Distribute a PySide GUI Program as a Python wheel with desktop icon
I have developed a GUI tool using PySide6 and PyQtGraph for correcting scientific data within my workgroup. To improve the update process and version control, I want to distribute the program as a Python wheel via pip.
My current approach below installs all the required dependencies, creates a batch file, and generates a desktop shortcut to this batch file with a custom logo.
Is it possible to recreate the desktop icon and custom logo via a Python wheel?
If so, how can I achieve this?
Current installer script:
import os
import subprocess
import sys

print("Starting SAXS Evaluator installation")
try:
    from win32com.client import Dispatch
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print("PyWin32 will be installed to create Desktop Shortcut")
    subprocess.run(["pip", "install", "--upgrade", "pywin32"])
    input("Restart the installer ...")
    from win32com.client import Dispatch

current_path: str = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path_venv: str = os.path.join(current_path, "venv")
path_script: str = os.path.join(current_path, r"SAXS_Evaluator_GUI.py")
path_icon: str = os.path.join(current_path, r"Icon\SAXS_Evaluator-Logo.ico")
path_batch: str = os.path.join(current_path, r"SAXSEvaluator.bat")


#### Virtual environment and install packages ###
def create_venv(venv_path):
    subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-m", "venv", venv_path])


def install_requirements():
    subprocess.run(["pip", "install", "-r", os.path.join(current_path,"requirements.txt")])


def create_batch_file(script_path: str = path_script,
                      batch_path: str = path_batch):
    batch_content = r"""@echo off
    set "batch_folder=%~dp0"
    set "project_path=%batch_folder%"
    
    echo Start SAXS Evaluator
    echo Software folder: %project_path%
    
    cd /d %project_path%
    python SAXS_Evaluator_GUI.py
    pause
    """
    with open(path_batch, "w") as batch_file:
        batch_file.write(batch_content)


def create_shortcut(target_path, shortcut_name="SAXSEvaluator", icon_path=None) -> None:
    """
    Create Desktop Shortcut
    Args:
        target_path: Folderpath for Shortcut
        shortcut_name: Name of the Shortcut on Desktop
        icon_path: Path so icon symbol
    """
    desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop")
    shortcut_path = os.path.join(desktop_path, f"{shortcut_name}.lnk")

    shell = Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
    shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(shortcut_path)
    shortcut.TargetPath = target_path

    if icon_path:
        shortcut.IconLocation = os.path.abspath(icon_path)
    shortcut.Save()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("pip install packages from requirements.txt")
    install_requirements()
    print("Packages installed")

    print("Create Batch File to start Software")
    create_batch_file(path_script)
    print("Create Shortcut on Desktop")
    create_shortcut(target_path=path_batch, icon_path=path_icon, shortcut_name="SAXS Evaluator")

    # wait for user input, after Installation
    input("installation complete. Press Enter to finish...")


